# how do i converting a face_recognition.face_distance result to a string and then back

Tags: python, list, numpy, face-recognition

I am new to python and currently been working with face_recognition, when getting the face_encoding of an image i understand it returns 128 points, when i print the results i see a list of floating numbers and thought i could just convert the list to a string so i am able to then store it easy in a file/database. Then when i want to do a distance calculation i could read that string back in and convert it back to a list and do a face_distance calculation, However this returned some errors. When doing some searching i found this is because its not a normal list and mentioned numpy arrays.

Doing some more searching i found an example of someone converting a numpy array to a sting and back which i tried but the results where completely different, when reading more about this it seems some meta data is lost in and out, and at this point come to a dead end.

What i am wanting to do is store the results of an image encoding to a database or file with reference to that image, so whenever i want to do run another image against it i don't have to keep doing the encoding part. I did find a hack which uses pickle to dump the object to a file and then allows me to read it back in which works but that seems very messy.

Comment: Actually, dumping the object is the solution. If you have multiple images and their vectors, then you can create a dictionary of them to be dumped.

Comment: ah ok, i think maybe i was to focused on seeing 128 floating numbers and thinking i could just store it like that in a database looking nice and tidy appose to a string/text that represents an object dump that has a lot of extended chars in.